Обновить таблицу Posrgres
Всем доброго времени суток!
Для себя решил попробовать вести таблицу поступлений в postgres через dbeaver.
Суть в том, что сначала данные поступают через скрипт python в csv.
И этот файл csv я импортировал в таблицу.
Поскольку файл csv каждый месяц обновляется, то у меня возник вопрос: можно ли сделать какую-то привязку таблицы к этому файлу? Чтобы не импортировать каждый месяц новый файл, как бы в режиме реального времени таблица postgres брала данные оттуда?
Спасибо!

В явном виде нет. Возможно(скорее всего) можно создать задание в БД, которое будет по расписанию вычитывать файл и добавлять данные в таблицу. Однако, т.к. у вас файл на "ручнике", то есть вероятность дублирования данных(если в файле нет полей, по которым можно наложить уникальный фильтр, например ID транзакции)

Файл обновляется примерно раз в месяц и все время лежит в одной папке. В таблице есть номера заказов, но иногда с одним номером заказа имеется несколько строчек в csv

Проще грузить вручную или автоматизировать сам csv файл, что бы не его получать, а сразу собирать заказы в БД

Вы имеете в виду по скрипту не в cab грузить, а сразу к БД подключаться и туда данные заливать?

Ну например так. Нет особого смысла, сначала файл создавать, а потом в БД грузить, когда можно сразу в БД все загрузить

Спасибо за ответ!

Создал таблицу, а потом решил сделать две задачи в Dbeaver: очистить таблицу; импортировать данные из файла

Создал таблицу, а потом решил сделать две задачи в Dbeaver: очистить таблицу; импортировать данные из файла
